# Need to convert a list of strings to a list of normal numbers, strings are base 10

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of integers looking like this:

```
["1e-04", "1e-06", "1e-08", "1e-10", "1e-12"]
```

I need to convert this list of strings into a list of normal numbers, but the base 10 gets me stuck. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: they can not be integers, but ok

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> import ast
>>> L = ["1e-04", "1e-06", "1e-08", "1e-10", "1e-12"]
>>> [ast.literal_eval(x) for x in L]
[0.0001, 1e-06, 1e-08, 1e-10, 1e-12]
```

Or simply..

```
>>> [float(x) for x in L]
[0.0001, 1e-06, 1e-08, 1e-10, 1e-12]
```

Comment: Because maybe for future readers they aren't all floats .. e.g. `literal_eval` would preserve a mix of integers and floats

Comment: I would use `literal_eval`, but it's probably worth pointing out that it won't help with the "special" values that `float` can take, such as `float('nan')` -- `literal_eval('nan')` (completely unsurprisingly) breaks...

Comment: +1 for using `ast.literal_eval`, which is safer than using `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `map` and `float`:

```
>>> values_as_strings = ["1e-04", "1e-06", "1e-08", "1e-10", "1e-12"
>>> values_as_floats = map(float, values_as_strings)
>>> print values_as_floats
[0.0001, 1e-06, 1e-08, 1e-10, 1e-12]
```

See [map](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map).

Answer (score 0):

a=[eval(i) for i in a] # here a is the list

this list comprehension will solve it